# Possible ways of comparing large records from one table on a database and another table on another database

Tags: python-3.x, database, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking into the ways for comparing records from same table but on different databases. I just need to compare and find the missing records.

I tried out a few methods.
loading the records into a pandas data frame, I used read_sql. But it is taking more time and memory to complete the load and if the records are large, I am getting a memory error.

Tried setting up a standalone cluster of spark and run the comparison,  it is also throwing java heap space error. tuning the conf is not working as well.

Please let me know if there are other ways to handle this huge record comparison.

--update

Do we have a tool readily available for cross data source comparison

Answer (score 0):

If your data size is huge you can use cloud services to run your spark job and get the results. Here you can use aws glue which is serverless and is charged as you go.

Or if your data is not considerably large and is something one time job then you can use google colab which is free and run your comparision over it .

Comment: That is a good Suggestion, Need to test that out before committing. Thankyou